# When convolution with exponential kernel is bounded

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, limits-and-convergence, lebesgue-measure, convolution

Let $g(t)=e^{-\omega t}$, $\omega>0$. What is, in terms of well-known function spaces, the space $X$, $L_{loc}^2(0,\infty)\subset X$, of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$, satisfying 
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}(g*f)(t)=\int_0^\infty g(t-s)f(s)ds<\infty.$$

Comment: This is phrased like an assignment question - where did you come across this problem?

Comment: It's not an assignment question :(
 It appears in the stability of some PDEs

Comment: What do you mean by $(g*f)(t)$? If by that you mean $\int_0^t g(t-s)f(s)ds=\int_0^t e^{-\omega(t-s)}f(s)ds$ (which would seem to be the only natural way given that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$), then, by the Schwarz inequality, $(g*f)(t)$ is clearly finite for all $f\in L_{loc}^2(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Notice the convolution is not bounded for all $f\in L^2_{loc}(0,\infty)$, e.g. $f(t)=e^t$.

Comment: More appropriate for MathStackExchange...

Comment: @IosifPinelis It's not so clear. Not that $f\in L_{loc}^2(0,\infty)$ so not imply that $f\in L^2(0,t)$ holds. Every continuous function that diverges towards infinity sufficiently badly at $0$ is a counterexample. But of course that shows that any such function will be an example where $g\ast f$ equals $+\infty$ everywhere, which again brings up the question how the convolution is supposed to be interpreted here.

Comment: made some improvement.

Comment: @JohannesHahn : I understood $L_{loc}^2(0,\infty)$ as $L_{loc}^2([0,\infty))$, just as usually $L^p(0,1)$ is understood as $L^p([0,1])$. Anyway, if the OP understood $L_{loc}^2(0,\infty)$ as $L_{loc}^2((0,\infty))$, then its subspace $L_{loc}^2([0+,\infty))$ consisting of all functions $f\in L_{loc}^2((0,\infty))$ with $f^2$ integrable on $(0,t)$ for every $t$ will serve the desired role. :-)

Comment: Since it's not an assignment question, it's better to not use the imperative tense, but actually ask a question.

Comment: Re-stated the question.